# JavaScript "onClick" on li elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a menu bar with `ul` and `li` and I want some `onClick` events linked to JavaScript functions.

But it does not work, clicking on menus don't do anything at all.

The function is on a JS file I already use and I tested it on another element, it seems that id doesn't work only inside of my `li`.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="titleContainer">
        blablabl
    </div>
    <ul id="menuContainer">
        <li class="menuItem" id="videoMenu">
            <a href="#" onClick="showAbout2();"> Video</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem" id="playlistMenu">
            Playlist
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem" id="aboutMenu">
            About
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem" id="controlsMenu">
            Controls
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
#titleContainer
{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
    color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#menuContainer
{
    background-color: #333333;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -1;
}

#menuContainer li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
```

The JS:

```
function showAbout2()
{
    console.log("bonjour");
}
```

---

**ANSWER:**

The answer was :

**Removing the z-index.**

---

I wanted to click on a lower-layered element.
So i'll try this http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/

Thanks everyone : )

Comment: Your markup hasn't been pasted correctly. Can we also see your javascript?

Comment: Adding a link to jsfiddle code might help even more :) thanks

Comment: I think your problem is with the `z-index: -1`.

Comment: Please put the answer into the answer section and accept (either Harry or the original poster).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `z-index` on the `#menuContainer`. This is pushing the `#menuContainer` behind and hence is preventing the click event from happening/taking effect.

```
#menuContainer
{
    background-color: #333333;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -1; /*Remove this line.*/
}
```

```js
function showAbout2() {
    console.log("bonjour");
}
```

```css
#titleContainer {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
    color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#menuContainer {
    background-color: #333333;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#menuContainer li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="titleContainer">blablabl</div>
    <ul id="menuContainer">
        <li class="menuItem" id="videoMenu"> <a href="#" onClick="showAbout2();"> Video</a>

        </li>
        <li class="menuItem" id="playlistMenu">Playlist</li>
        <li class="menuItem" id="aboutMenu">About</li>
        <li class="menuItem" id="controlsMenu">Controls</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

> The below update is not part of the original question but is added based on your comments to the answer.

It seems like removing the `z-index: -1` is breaking the `box-shadow` effect on your website because it is bringing the element back to the front. To overcome this, add the below lines to `#titleContainer` and `#mainContent` after removing the item mentioned in the original answer

```
z-index: 2; 
position: relative;
```

That will get the shadow back because instead of sending `#menuContainer` back, we are bringing the other two in front.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I answered on thgaskell answer

Comment: Thank you but its not totally answered eheh !
Now i can click but it is braking the effect i wanted (shadow on the element).
See : ogdabou.com
I let the z-index for you to see the effect ^^

Comment: @ogdabou: Yes, I can see that. Will try and see if I can correct it.

Comment: Oh.. thank you, i'll try this think http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/
But it feels like using a bazooka

Comment: @ogdabou: After removing the item mentioned in the answer, add `z-index: 2; position: relative;` to `#titleContainer` and `#mainContent`. That will get the shadow back. Basically instead of sending `menuContainer` back, I am bringing the other two in front.

Comment: @ogdabou: Always glad to be of help mate :)

Comment: Downvoter, it would be helpful if you can leave a comment with the reason for your downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `z-index: -1`, it's preventing you from clicking the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/w4cE3/

#### CSS

```
#menuContainer
{
    background-color: #333333;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, the click is working now...
But the z-index : -1
was used to do a style effect (see ogdabou.com the menu, it is between the header and the main content). If i remove it the shados aren't visible anymore

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is loop through the list-item elements and add event listeners...

```
 var l = document.getElementById('menuContainer').getElementsByTagName('li');

 for (var i=0; i<l.length; i++)
 {
  l[i].addEventListener('click', function() {alert('add any function in place of this alert!');},false);
 }
```

If you need something more specific please comment.

Comment: This worked for me however I had to replace the `onclick` with `click`. I'm running IE 9. Thanks.

Comment: @T3.0 Yes, older versions of IE will require the "on" prefix which is not standard in scripting itself (only in HTML attributes).

Answer (score 0):

You have to Remove the z-index on the id tag #menuContainer. This should work

```
#menuContainer{
background-color: #333333;
line-height: 35px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
```